# while loop. random number appearing

Tags: c++, while-loop

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double number;

    while(number <= 100)
    {
        cout << number << endl;
        number++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that I need to initialize the variable, but out of curiosity, why does the compiler print out this very small number at the beginning of the output?

Comment: Because it can. When undefined behavior is invoked, the compiler is allowed to print any junk, or even make a program that crashes.

Comment: Because it's **_undefined behaviour_**. It can do whatever.

Comment: initialise "number" variable. local variables will not initialise to 0. If not initialised some memory will be used at run time which can have any value inside.

Comment: It doesn't show it [here](http://ideone.com/teWJCJ).  That's undefined behavior in action.

Answer (score 2):

That because you not initialize value for number ... You can check cout<< number; before loop. You can see the output..